# Правильное именование ресурсов Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь сделать нормальную иерархию ресурсов, чтобы было удобно работать. Как правильно давать название файлам? Допустим,в папке Drawable есть XML файл, в котором написан стиль кнопки, ее цвет, ее фигура и т.п., и данная кнопка используется только в первом activity и есть XML-файл кнопки, которая используется во втором activity. Т.е. названия я должен дать "button_one_activity_one" и "button_one_activity_two"? Как будет правильней ?

Comment: делайте так, как вам будет удобней. Никаких особых правил нет. Но в качестве совета могу сказать, что лучше называть их так, как будто вы разнесли их по директориям. Например, `activity_1`, `activity_with_three_buttons`. Т.е. в названии от общего к частному - будет легче ориентироваться

Comment: @Jarvis_J Т.е.. в начале должно быть само название активити - типа activity1_with_three_buttons или activity_2_with_two_imageview ?

Comment: как вам удобно. Я называю по функционалу: `activity_start`, `activity_choose`, `dialog_exit`, `dialog_preferences` и т.п., мне удобно)

Comment: @Jarvis_J понял, спасибо)

Comment: На местоположение лучше вообще не завязываться, это касается любых названий. Иначе потом малейший рефакторинг превращается в ад :)